# how to prepare HttpSerlvetRequest object with complete header information

Tags: java, spring, junit

How to make HttpServletRequest Object for Junit Test. with completed header information like content-type,status-code,method,mime type,language etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Spring you can use the class : 
`org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest`

Here is an example for a http request  posting a json object :

```
final MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest(HttpMethod.POST.name(), "path for request");
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.setContentType("application/json");
request.setContent(this.gson.toJson(object).getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Suppose if I use content type is multiparty/form-data then how to add information in request object                       thanks.

Comment: You can use `Apache Commons HttpClient`   `MultipartRequestEntity` class. See the following [link](https://devnotesblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/mocking-a-multipartform-data-http-request-in-a-unit-test/)